# Raspbian Lite / Raspberry Pi 4. Какие зависимости нужно установить, для создания окон с Python?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

Установлена консольная (не  настольная) верстя операционной системы. Не хочется ради нескольких окон на Python, которые нужны, устанавливать настольную версию операционки, которая будет отнимать как я понимаю ресурсы. Какие зависимости, и что нужно установить в  Raspbian Lite, чтоб можно было создавать окна типа Tkinter() Python? В данный момент выходят какие то ошибки  типа $DISPLAY, что то в этом роде (я новичок в этом)

Comment: Не уверен, что возможно сделать графическое окно в  **консольной** операционной системе, звучит довольно абсурдно. Лучше все таки поставить графическую ос, и сделать приложение например на том же самом **Tkinter**

Comment: Ну можно доставить графику, но это действительно будет жрать ресурсы. Если очень хочется по минимуму, то вам в  сторону SDL (и соответственно python-SDL) на fbdev (frame buffer) смотреть надо.

Comment: Почему бы не посмотреть в сторону curses?

Comment: @0andriy Qt можно запускать на голом фреймбуфере, но сколько того не  пробовал оно того не стоит для мелкосерийных проектов.

Comment: @Allespro snack интереснее курсес в плане простых диалогов

Comment: @eri Qt сильно “жирная” по сравнению с SDL, но зато менюшки проще рисовать. Есть ещё directFB для низкоуровневого варианта.

Comment: qt если статикой собрать, то можно запускать на голом kms прямо из initramfs =)

Comment: Поставьте туда, откуда вы заходите на Pi, X-сервер, и будут вам окошки. ssh прекрасно пробрасывает иксы.

Answer (score 0):

Абсолютно не важно, будете Вы использовать *TkInter, Qt, Wx* или что-то другое. Любая графическая библиотека, в конце концов, обращается к Х11 (Wayland), без которого работа невозможна в принципе. Присоединяюсь к Allespro в части *ncurses*.

Можно ещё попробовать утилиты командной строки типа :

```
notify-send 'Заголовок' 'Сообщение'
zenity --question --text="Желаете продолжить работу?"
```

Подробнее смотрите тут: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144924/how-can-i-create-a-message-box-from-the-command-line

Но я не уверен, что это сработает без Х-сервера.

Comment: Очередной ваш «ответ» с утверждением, несоответствующим действительности. Почитайте, что ли, литературу и код?

Answer (score 0):

Не получится рисовать окна до того как установили графику - тут проблема курицы и яйца =)

В пакете `python3-newt` есть модуль `snack`, который рисует окна в текстовой консоли через ту же библиотеку, что и установщики debian и ubuntu.

```
from snack import *

screen = SnackScreen()

ret = EntryWindow(screen, 'Title', 'My super agenda', 
        ['name', 'lastname', 'age'])

screen.finish()

status = ret[0]
values = ret[1]

# OK or Cancel
print ("Pressed %s" % (status))

# Print every single item
for item in values:
    print (item)
```